# Unsupervised deep artificial neural network classifier for rare occurrences of an event

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, unsupervised-learning, deep-learning

I built and trained an unsupervised deep artificial neural network to detect high-order features from a large data set.

The data consists of daily weather measurements, and the output of the last layer of my deep net is 4 neurons wide, which hopefully represent high-order features.
Now I would like to detect the probability of a very rare event (e.g. a tornado).
I singled-out the data points that resulted in a tornado, but there are very few of them, about `10,000 out of 5,000,000` data points.

```
What's the best design for my tornado classifier?
```

- create a training set made of only the 10,000 `tornado` data points, with a desired output of 1 each time?
- create a training set made of all 5,000,000 data points, with desired output 0 when there is no tornado, and 1 when there is one? but that will likely never predict a tornado.
- other solutions?

Comment: `a training set made of all 5,000,000 data points, with desired output 0 when there is no tornado, and 1 when there is one? [...] will likely never predict a tornado` I am no expert on neither weather nor neural networks though I have dabbled in the latter. I am curious why you discount this approach as a likely path to success.

Comment: Initial empirical tests seem to suggest that the overwhelming amount of negatives simply trains the network to ignore positives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you are using unsupervised learning. It sounds like a purely supervised learning task.

You shouldn't throw away data for predicting rare events. If an event is very rare than of course the network will predict it has a very low probability. Because it does. This is called "bias". However the rest of the network should still try it's hardest to learn to distinguish positive and negative examples.

If you don't like that you can try a different loss function. Perhaps a loss function that punishes missing positive examples more than negative examples. Or you can change the networks bias just by adding more copies of the positive examples to the dataset.

You would be better off asking Data Science Stack Exchange btw: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I use unsupervised learning to detect high-order features from the bulk of data, and feed these features to the classifier that I train using supervised learning. I think it's called semi-supervised learning. Your answer definitely shed light on my problem. Thank you very much. I wasn't aware of the existence of a data science section on stack exchange, but I'll definitely post there next time.